# Why is spotifyd daemon failing to start

Tags: terminal, spotify

Every time I run the command `brew services start spotifyd` on my terminal, the error `` Error: Failure while executing; `/bin/launchctl bootstrap gui/501 /Users/homefolder/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.spotifyd.plist` exited with 5. `` appears, preventing me from using the service.

I have tried:
`sudo launchctl stop /Library/LaunchDaemons/rustlang.spotifyd.plist` followed by `sudo launchctl unload -w /Library/LaunchDaemons/rustlang.spotifyd.plist` and then `sudo launchctl load -w /Library/LaunchDaemons/rustlang.spotifyd.plist` followed by `sudo launchctl start /Library/LaunchDaemons/rustlang.spotifyd.plist` and finally `brew services restart spotifyd`

But the issue remains

Answer (score 0):

Well, I ended up finding a solution to the issue... running the command `brew services restart spotifyd` as root, meaning `sudo brew services restart spotifyd` actually allows for successful execution.